# Central Database With The Databases Residing on Client PC?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Central Database(MySQL) on the Server whose copy is made on Every Client machine upon execution of Application .

1. When a Client Machine wants to Access Any Data it refers to the Copy Of The Central Database present on his local System .
2. When a Client Machine Wants to Update any Value it Does So in the Central Database.
3. The Challenge I am Facing is in Updating the Local DB's across all clients once a change has been made on the Central Server in the fastest manner possible.

Comment: Look for replication

Comment: Really vague question - but this is a difficult architecture to develop and manage. How many client machines? Are they reliably connected to the server, or will they be used off-line? How much data are you synchronizing?

Comment: There are 20 Client machines. Yes they are reliably connected to the server.And it is a Multiplayer Wargame that i am developing , so you can have a scenario where there are 100 units(Surface Ships/Sub-Marines/Air Units) whose details(Weapons Status/Logistics Status/Communication Equipment Status) are being updated in a very small time resolution by the client Machines on the Central Database which in turn needs to be reflected on the client machines.